# Action after clicking button on Facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, dom-events

I put an iframe from a Facebook page, I put Javascript code that allows you to launch alert after click like:

```js
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  alert('ora segui aggiornamenti: ' + response);
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
  alert('Non segui gli aggiornamenti: ' + response);
});

};
```

Is there a similar function that allows us to run a function after clicking the subscribe button?

The full code of this page:

```js
< html >
  < head >
  < script >
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '1664052443882672',
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.5'
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
      alert('ora segui aggiornamenti: ' + response);
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
      alert('Non segui gli aggiornamenti: ' + response);
    });

  };

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/us_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); < /script>
    
</head >
< body >

  < div class = "fb-page"
data - tabs = "events"
data - href = "https://www.facebook.com/RoyalDream8"
data - width = "2000"
data - action = "subscribe"
data - hide - cover = "false" > < /div>
    
</body >
  < /html>
```

Comment: No, there is no event for that.

Comment: Btw., are you actually writing HTML code in that weird way (whitespace before/after `<` and `>`, in(!) attribute names) …?

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the existing events in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

As of now, there is no event for it.